# How do I implement recoil on a gun in LUA, 2D?

Tags: lua, rotation, delay, coronasdk

I'm trying to create a gun simulator type mobile application, and am currently trying to code a fire function. it's going pretty well so far, but me being a novice I'm having troubles figuring out what I can do to resolve my issue:

```
function pistolRecoil()
transition.to(pistol, {time = 30, rotation = -20 })
end

function revPistolRecoil()
transition.to(pistol, {time = 50, rotation = 20 })
end

--Fire the pistol--
function tapFirePistol (event)
--display flash
muzzleFlashP:toFront()
timer.performWithDelay(20, muzzleFlashPFunc())
pistolAmmo = pistolAmmo - 1
----timings
--sound(.wav),
audio.play(pFireSound)
--rotate,rotate
pistolRecoil()
print("1st", pistol.rotation)
pistolRecoil()
print("2nd", pistol.rotation)
revPistolRecoil()
----timings
if pistolAmmo <= 0 then fireButtonPistol:removeEventListener("tap", 
tapFirePistol)
pistolAmmoCount.text = pistolAmmo
end
if pistolAmmo <= 0 then pistolAmmo = 0
pistolAmmoCount.text = pistolAmmo
end
pistolAmmoCount.text = pistolAmmo
end

fireButtonPistol:addEventListener("tap", tapFirePistol)
```

The problem I'm having is that the gun will recoil, but stay rotated, which is bad as I would like it to "fall" back down after a short period of time, and will not recoil any further even in the fire button is tapped while the pistol is still rotated (which I'm not bothered by)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: you already use timer.performWithDelay for the muzzle flash. what stops you from using it to bring the pistol down after a while?

Comment: the timer.performWithDelay doesn't display the muzzleFlash. I dont know whether its down to my current path to the image but I was using muzzleFlashP.isVisible = true and muzzleFlashP.isVisible = false to hide and show the flash, but I would never be able to see it for long enough. so I guess the short answer would be because I don't understand how it works.

Comment: maybe you should make sure the existing features work then befor you add more? just an advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the recoil aspect is now working as I am now using timer.performWithDelay. I found out that the reason the timer.performWithDelay was not behaving the way I expected is because i was using parenthesis inside the performWithDelay parenthesis, which are not needed, and I also specified that it should be done once.

```
timer.performWithDelay(20, revPistolRecoil, 1)
```

I still call pistolRecoil as a function.

As a side note, the muzzleFlashP also now works when I apply the same changes.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: they are not just "not needed". having parenthesis inside will replace the function variable to call with it's return value. so it will result in a totally different, possibly wrong behaviour or even errors. Lua will call revPistiolRecoil and then call performWithDelay with revPistolRecoil's return value which performWithDelay will then try to call. Now without parenthesis performWithDelay gets a function variable and calls it. So in both scenarios your function was called. In the first one it was called immediately in the second one after the desired delay.